# rethinkDB: group by partial value

Tags: rethinkdb

I am evaluating phone call logs, which I have imported into rethinkDB; the documents look like this:

```
{
    'date': '2015-01-02',
    'duration': 46,
    'cost': 0.25
    'type': 'outgoing'
}
```

I am trying to retrieve a **sum for the duration of all calls in a month**.

I could "manually" achieve it with this query:

```
r.table('CallLog').filter(r.row('date').match('2015-01-*')).sum('duration')
```

and given that I only need it for 6 months, it is absolutely possible to do it within a reasonable time. However, I'd rather figure out a way to do it in one query.
I know that I can group documents; e.g. to sum up the costs of all calls by call type I could do

```
r.table('CallLog').group('type').sum('cost')
```

What I do not know, though is **how I can group by a partial field**, in this case the first 7 characters of the `date` field.
Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by a partial field by passing an anonymous functions to your `group` method. Any time you want some special behavior out of a `group` function think about in anonymous functions (lambda functions).

In this case, you can use the [`match`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/match/) method to pass a regular expression that will match a string with 4 digits a dash and 2 digits (`\\d{4}-\\d{2}`).

Here's how the query would look:

```
r.table('29969411')
  .group(function (row) {
    return row('date').match("\\d{4}-\\d{2}")
  }).sum('cost')
```

Give the following entries in a table:

```
{
    "cost": 0.25 ,
    "date":  "2015-02-02" ,
    "duration": 46 ,
    "id":  "1ff56fdd-9152-4729-baa4-c9736adbe54f" ,
    "type":  "outgoing"
}, {
    "cost": 0.25 ,
    "date":  "2015-03-02" ,
    "duration": 46 ,
    "id":  "74a453ec-531c-4fb0-a463-661b122d47df" ,
    "type":  "outgoing"
}, {
    "cost": 0.25 ,
    "date":  "2015-01-02" ,
    "duration": 46 ,
    "id":  "bfa9aa42-51c0-43ef-af3d-24de15ed6571" ,
    "type":  "outgoing"
}, {
    "cost": 0.25 ,
    "date":  "2015-01-99" ,
    "duration": 46 ,
    "id":  "c93ac248-f214-4649-a355-bfc814169456" ,
    "type":  "outgoing"
}
```

The result would be as follows:

```
[
  {
    "group": {
    "end": 7 ,
    "groups": [ ],
    "start": 0 ,
    "str":  "2015-01"
  } ,
   "reduction": 0.5
  } ,
  {
    "group": {
    "end": 7 ,
    "groups": [ ],
    "start": 0 ,
    "str":  "2015-02"
  } ,
   "reduction": 0.25
  } ,
  {
    "group": {
    "end": 7 ,
    "groups": [ ],
    "start": 0 ,
    "str":  "2015-03"
  } ,
    "reduction": 0.25
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, Jorge; in the meantime I have found (with some help) another one, too:

```
r.table('CallLog').group(r.row('date').match('.{7}')('str')).sum('cost')
```

which gives the following result:

```
[
    {
        "group":"2014-09",
        "reduction":214.8195
    },
    {
        "group":"2014-10",
        "reduction":20087.655200000074
    }
]
```

Comment: Yeap! It's basically the same idea. My regex is a bit more specific though. That might or might not be what you want.

Comment: If the answer you or I provided answers your question, make sure to mark as 'solved' so that it's clear for people who visit this question later on!

Comment: you're right, the way I filter is very specific to my particular data, where I now for sure that the 'date' field has the layout yyyy-mm-dd; your regex solution is more "general purpose"